# Why couldn't Sherlock figure out that there was no glass between him and Eurus?

Tags: plot-explanation, sherlock

I don't really get the episode *The Final Problem* in the *Sherlock* series. But what I find most amazing is that Sherlock who can basically predict the future 2 weeks in advance can't notice that there was no glass between him and Eurus.

Eurus had a mic to mimic the voice inside glass. But what about the violin she was playing? Couldn't Sherlock notice it? And suppose if the violin also had a mic on it like Eurus then when Sherlock played it, why couldn't he figure out that the violin's sound was not right?

I mean I can't just understand that a person so brilliant like Sherlock couldn't figure out that there was no glass behind him and Eurus?

Comment: I think that it's related to the fact that Sherlock is so eager to meet the sister he didn't know existed and talking to her, that he doesn't notice the glass missing.

Comment: @Gustavo Gabriel Sherlock & exited & didn't notice there was no glass? Doesn't it seem like a bit out of character for him?

Comment: he was observing her, not the room

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was one of the badly portrayed parts in the Sherlock episodes.

If you want to get into like a real reason for why Sherlock might have not seen the glass not being there is because he wouldn't have even expected the glass not being there. Eurus must have caught him off-guard.

If Sherlock had known something was up, he probably would have noticed that there was no light reflecting off the glass, since there was none.

Comment: IIRC in his analysis after he realizes it, he mentioned that Eurus made sure there wouldn't be anything _to_ reflect, so an absence wouldn't be noticeable. Other than that, Sherlock seeing his long lost (and pretty much forgotten about) sister is of the most likely things to preoccupy him, so it's not that far-fetched that he misses to spot a trick devised by someone smarter than him.

Comment: You really don't have to add "Hope this answers your question." in every post.